# openvpn --config client.ovpn fail: RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Tags: openvpn

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 Mate

> sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn

results

> Initialization Sequence Completed

with errors

```
Tue May 30 23:54:41 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Tue May 30 23:54:41 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.10.10.3/24 broadcast 10.10.10.255
Tue May 30 23:54:45 2017 /sbin/ip route add 188.93.88.146/32 via 192.168.0.1
Tue May 30 23:54:45 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.1.1.0/24 via 10.10.10.1
Tue May 30 23:54:45 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.1.1.1/32 via 10.10.10.1
Tue May 30 23:54:45 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.1.1.2/32 via 10.10.10.1
Tue May 30 23:54:45 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.1.1.1/32 via 10.10.10.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Tue May 30 23:54:45 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Tue May 30 23:54:45 2017 /sbin/ip route add 188.93.88.146/32 via 192.168.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Tue May 30 23:54:45 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Tue May 30 23:54:45 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` looks like

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`$ ip link show` results

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp8s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:64:a9:bf:10:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:08:b1:1f:3c:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`$ route` results

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```

I have tried

```
$ sudo ip addr flush dev wlo1

$ sudo ip addr flush dev enp8s0
```

and restarting, but errors still occur when connecting with openvpn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed `route remote_host 255.255.255.255 net_gateway` from `client.ovpn` file

Comment: This doesn't answer or explains the original problem.. can't see how this could possibly be an accepted answer.

Comment: It's odd but I've been having the same issues with OpenVPN and disabling that line has solved the issue for me as well. I'm not sure why but it's working for me

Answer (score 1):

`/sbin/ip route add 10.1.1.1/32 via 10.10.10.1` and `/sbin/ip route add 188.93.88.146/32 via 192.168.0.1` are both being executed on previous lines, resulting in the `File Exists` errors. Removing those duplicates will solve your problem (I believe).